# Click button in using VBA selenium Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click a button using a VBA Chrome driver via Selenium but I get a NoSuchElement error

The HTML code for the button is -

```
<button _ngcontent-ban-c26="" class="large-button-primary width marTop16"><span _ngcontent-ban-c26=""> Continue <!----><img _ngcontent-ban-c26="" alt="" class="ng-star-inserted" src="https://static.incometax.gov.in/iec/foservices/assets/buttonIcons/nextIconPrimary.svg"><!----><!----><!----></span></button>
```

but when I try to click the button using the following code, i get the error -

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[.//span[text()='Continue']]").Click
```

Comment: I am not an expert on Selenium: I would try this statement `obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[//span[contains(text()='Continue')]]").Click`